# How to use two renderers with structlog?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, structlog

Would anyone of you know how to use two different renderers in [structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/)?

I'd like to use [ConsoleRenderer](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer) with colors and nice formatting in console (on DEBUG) and also log same messages in log, without colors and on INFO level.

Here is my current configuration:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import structlog
from structlog.stdlib import BoundLogger

logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "handlers": {
            "default": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            },
            "file": {
                "level": "INFO",
                "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
                "filename": "/var/tmp/test.log",
            },
        },
        "loggers": {
            "": {
                "handlers": ["default", "file"],
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "propagate": True,
            },
        },
    }
)


structlog.stdlib.recreate_defaults(log_level=None)
structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.contextvars.merge_contextvars,
        structlog.processors.add_log_level,
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
        structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(colors=False),
    ],
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=BoundLogger,
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
)
```

Comment: Since you're using standard library logging, you'll have to solve this within `logging`. It should be possible using the most complicated stdlib approach documented here: https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-using-structlog-based-formatters-within-logging There's also https://pypi.org/project/multistructlog/ but I'm not sure that works for your use case.